# Elasticsearch - How to down sample large datasets

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out how to query a large dataset so I could put it up on a js line chart.
The index has millions of documents and I want to be able to show the entire series even if it's zoomed out.

The mapping kinda looks like this:

```
{
    "counter": {
        "type": long // used as kind of a sequential ID
    },
    "deposits": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "depositA": { "type": "long" },
            "depositB": { "type": "long" }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show a line chart where the X axis is the `counter` values and the Y axis is the sum of the `depositA` and `depositB` values.

The dataset has about 7M docs so I'm thinking if I could get ES to return the average of every 7 rows,I could trim that down to 1M points for my chart and still have something that looks sensible. Possibly, even take it down to 100k points?

The problem is I don't really know where to start and I'm just very new to ES.

I tried histogram aggregations but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

```
POST /data/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "counters": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "counter",
        "interval": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While this returns the `counter` field in 50 intervals, it also only gives me a doc count in those 50 counters (which I guess is just how histograms work?). I would like to know how to get the average value of depositA+depositB across the 50 items along with the counter keys, if possible.

I'm really over my head here honestly but would love to learn.
If anyone could point me to any helpful information that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, histogram aggregation is the correct way to go, as I see. I think you need to put sub-aggregation on it. Here is an example for you:

```
POST indexa/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": "1"}}
{"counter": 1, "deposits": {"depositA": 10, "depositB": 15}}
{"index": {"_id": "2"}}
{"counter": 2, "deposits": {"depositA": 12, "depositB": 17}}
{"index": {"_id": "3"}}
{"counter": 3, "deposits": {"depositA": 16, "depositB": 16}}
{"index": {"_id": "4"}}
{"counter": 4, "deposits": {"depositA": 18, "depositB": 18}}



POST indexa/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "range": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "counter",
        "interval": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "deposits"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "scripts": {
              "avg": {
                "script": {
                  "lang": "painless", 
                  "source": "return doc['deposits.depositA'].value + doc['deposits.depositB'].value"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think this will work for you. I put an `avg` aggregation with sub-aggregation. I used nested aggregation because your deposits field is nested typed.

Comment: This worked like a charm and is exactly what I needed. Thank you. If you don't mind, could you send me resources for where you learned this? For my own edification. Thank you again.

Comment: Nice to hear the answer worked for you. I am mainly looking at the documentation of Elasticsearch and experiencing different problems while consulting the companies.

Comment: Hello again, I wanted to ask what the top aggregation (named range) is called. I'm trying to convert this query to this golang package https://github.com/olivere/elastic and I'm confused as to what needs to be used. Is it a terms aggregation?

Comment: I see. There is a `range` aggregation in elasticsearch but I did not use it. Maybe because of this you confused a little bit. You need to user `histogram` aggregation named as "range".

Comment: On the other side, I did not use that client before. I don't know how you can implement with that client.

Comment: Thanks. I posted a question on how to achieve this query on the client's github issues. I think I have figured it out but would still would appreciate your input if you have any. https://github.com/olivere/elastic/issues/1659

Comment: As I see, you are doing correctly in your example. In fact, I want to try golang but I don't have any environment to execute go on my machine. Let me try to find an online compiler to test it. This takes time :)